# Prove $ \sin^4(x)$ identity using $z=cis(x)?$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I cannot prove the $\sin^4(x)$ identity using $z= cis(x)$. I know that you have to use de Moivre's theorem and compare the real values of $z^4$ but I am stuck at this step:
$$\sin^4(x)= -\cos^4(x) + 6\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x) + \cos(4x)$$

The identity is $\sin^4(x) = 1/8(\cos(4x) - 4\cos(2x) + 3)$

Comment: `the sin^4(x) identity` ***Which*** identity? Be sure to spell out what you mean to really ask.

Comment: Use Moivre's theorem on one side and the [Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) on the other.  $\cos(4x)+i\sin(4x)=(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^4=\cos^4(x)+4\cos^3(x)i\sin(x)+6\cos^2(x)i^2\sin^2(x)+4\cos(x)i^3\sin^3(x)+\sin^4(x)$.

Comment: the identity is sin^4(x) = 1/8(cos(4x) - 4cos(2x) + 3)

Comment: @VarunJahagirdar Click `edit` under your question and add it there, not as a comment.

Comment: it is the same question but they have not answered the question using complex numbers

Comment: They have answered the question using complex numbers, you can just replace $e^{i\theta} = cis(\theta)$ and you'd have the same answer. So I'd say this is probably a duplicate.

Comment: @VarunJahagirdar MPW’s answer certainly uses complex numbers.

Comment: Yes that is true... but I haven't yet learnt the use of Euler's number sorry

Comment: @VarunJahagirdar Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$cos 4x+i\sin4x=(\cos x+i\sin x)^4$$

then use

$$(a+b)^4=a^4+4a^3b+6a^2b^2+4ab^3+b^4$$

which leads to

- $\sin {4x}= 4\cos^3 x\sin x-4\cos x\sin^3x$
- $\cos 4x= \cos^4 x-6\cos^2 x\sin^2 x+\sin^4 x$

from the last we can obtain $\sin^4x$ using that

- $\cos^2 x=1-\sin^2x$
- $\cos 2x=\cos^2x-\sin^2x=1-2\sin^2x$

Comment: I don't think that's true because (isinx)^4 = sin^4(x) which is Real

Comment: Yes sorry, I indicated incorrectly at first, now I hope the method is clear.